# "we are pretty close in our hearts" VS "our hearts are pretty close"

Tags: sentence-choice

Is the following line a ill-expressed sentence?

> 1. Even though there is a great distance between us, we are pretty close in our hearts

Certainly, the writer was intended to send out the following message:

> 2. Even though there is a great distance between us, our hearts are pretty close.

I believe, the writer intended to say: Despite the fact we are living far away from each other, we have each other in our heart, and distance cannot separate our hearts. Can you give me more examples of such usage if the first line is rightly written?

Comment: The first line is grammatically correct but not idiomatic. Readers have to guess at its intended meaning.

Comment: Neither would likely be used in conversation English, unless you were conjoined twins.

Comment: @RonaldSole Could you kindly give me an idiomatic expression here?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How would we say this in conversation English.

Comment: Not sure what you mean to say -- are your *thoughts* similar? your *beliefs*? That you still like each other, despite differences?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I believe, the writer intended to say: Despite the fact we are living far away from each other, we have each other in our hearts, and distance cannot separate our hearts.

Comment: Yes -- or it could be *emotional* separation, rather than physical (e.g. political differences). Without context, there's no way to tell.